# Typescript: Conditional Types is not assignable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I try to build a function that utilizes the argument `returnType` to infer function return types. Here is my code:

```js
type ReturnTypes = "string" | "date";
type StringOuput = string | undefined;
type DateOutput = Date | undefined;
type ObjectType<T> = T extends "string"
  ? StringOuput
  : T extends "date"
  ? DateOutput
  : never;

function filterValue<T extends ReturnTypes>(
  returnType: ReturnTypes = "string"
): ObjectType<T> {
  switch (returnType) {
    case "date":
      return new Date();
    default:
      return "s";
  }
}

filterValue('string'); // s
filterValue('date') // some date value
```

However, I keep getting the TypeScript error

[image: error]

How can I fix the error or is there a better way to write this function?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: This is essentially a current TS limitation... generic conditional types are essentially opaque to the type checker; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a relevant feature request, and the answer to the linked question for more information.